# NSURLRequest returning null data (but only sometimes)

Tags: iphone, null, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to extract some data from a craigslist HTML page, but I seem to be running into a strange bug- every once in a while, the page I try to load with an NSURLRequest comes back as some strange form of data, which when converted to a parseable string, returns `null`. However, I can't consistently reproduce it- it'll suddenly stop working, and then I'll try it again an hour later and it'll be working perfectly, and then some time later it'll stop working again. Anyone know what could be causing it? I'm using an NSURLRequest, asynchronous, with the 'didReceiveData' and 'didReceiveResponse' delegate methods. If I cast the NSURLResponse to an NSHTTPURLResponse and check the response code, I get 200, meaning there were no issues. But when I go to initialize a string with the response data, it returns `null`, and I obviously then can't parse it.

The URL that seems to do it most often is: http://sarasota.craigslist.org/app/

I've tried messing with the User-Agent header for the request, the cache policy, everything I can think of... but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: have you taken a look at the response data ? what does it look like ?

Comment: @Matt If I directly log the incremental data as it comes in, I get a bunch of gibberish, which means there is data there, but if I convert it to a string with `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and then log that string it returns `null`.

Comment: Hi. I wonder if craigslist detects connections to parse data and throttles the activity? I've not looked in craigs but are you using a specific API or just connecting and scraping?

Comment: @MightyLeader I thought that might be the case as well, since I'm just grabbing the HTML page and scraping it. However, there only seem to be a couple of Craigslist categories that exhibit the behavior- the vast majority of the rest of them have no troubles loading reliably every time I make a request. (i.e. the example URL I posted is for the 'Appliances' category- the 'Electronics' category (and most others) load reliably all the time, and no matter how often I hit them)

Comment: I guess you could try detecting a null response and retry?

Comment: Actually I just had another thought. I've had issues before with carriers on iPhone intercepting and blocking requests because of content censoring and filtering. Might be worth considering.

Comment: @MightyLeader I could, but the problem is, the null return data doesn't just happen once and then work the next time after- it happens for a half hour, hour,... straight. And then all of the sudden it just start working again. And the carrier restrictions is a good thought, but the issue also happens on WiFi.

Comment: Hmmm... I suppose my next thought would be load issues at the server end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is data but when you ask for a string it's null then I might suspect the string encoding you're using to decode the data? Is there an odd character that is only sometimes in craigs list advert titles?

Just out of interest, why don't you use the rss feed instead - it's probably more consistently formatted / strictly encoded as it's xml not html.

> http://sarasota.craigslist.org/app/index.rss

Comment: Because the RSS feeds are limited to the latest 25, 50, something... posts.

Comment: Yep, string encoding was incorrect. Changing it fixed the issue.